# Azure release pipelines task - Copy Files task not copying the files

Tags: azure

I am having issue with the Files Copy task under the Azure release pipelines. The logs says file has been copied but it’s just copying the folders.

Here is the screen capture of the Copy Files task:

[Files Copy Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRFs8.png)

Logs:

> 2019-05-03T08:27:52.3448500Z found 10 files
>
> 2019-05-03T08:27:52.3449145Z Cleaning target folder:
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data\
>
> 2019-05-03T08:27:52.3483083Z Copying
>   D:\a\r1\a\Dev-CI\drop\Base\Settings.yml to
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data\Base\Settings.yml
>
> 2019-05-03T08:27:52.3483083Z Copying
>   D:\a\r1\a\Dev-CI\drop\Base\Common\Settings.yml to
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data\Base\Common\Settings.yml

As per above logs I am expecting, all the files should get copied with same folder structure under the D:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Data\ folder. But only folders are being copied.

Am I missing any configurations? Can anyone help me here?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

it is caused by the "filter" settings:

```
**\* copies all files in the specified source folder and all files in all sub-folders.
```

Means it will copy the file including the sub-folder

Please check here the same issue with resolution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587282/copy-one-file-in-target-directory-on-deploy-from-visual-studio-team-services

Especially how to flatten the folder structure:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46230842/5528792